# Does replacing template with namespace cause serious trouble for my code

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces

If I have a code similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class compare
{
public:
    bool comparison(T a,T b)
    {
        return (a>b);
    }

};

int main()
{

    int a=6,b=5;
    compare<int> cmp_i;
    std::cout<<cmp_i.comparison(a,b)<<std::endl;

    double c=7.0,d=7.5;
    compare<double> cmp_d;
    std::cout<<cmp_d.comparison(c,d)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and since I am very inclined to remove template from my program I use namespaces to solve the problem:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace int_space
{
    typedef int T;
    #include "base.hpp"
}

namespace double_space
{
    typedef double T;
    #include "base.hpp"
}

int main()
{

    int a=6,b=5;
    int_space::compare cmp_i;
    std::cout<<cmp_i.comparison(a,b)<<std::endl;

    double c=7.0,d=7.5;
    double_space::compare cmp_d;
    std::cout<<cmp_d.comparison(c,d)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

base.hpp:

```
class compare
{
public:
    bool comparison(T a,T b)
    {
        return (a>b);
    }
};
```

Both do the same thing but the second one does not use any template.

I wonder if this trick makes any serious problem for the future of my code when extending.

Comment: Yes. Anybody but you will wonder why you hand-rolled your own class template replacement.

Comment: @gha.st using templates sometimes incredibly increases the compile time in g++

Comment: Not for templates as simple as this, and repeated inclusion usually increases compile time compared to using actual templates, not decrease.

Answer (score 0):

> Does replacing template with namespace cause serious trouble for my code?

You are hand coding templates instead of letting the compiler generate code for template instantiations.

It seems simple for a class template for a single template parameter and one or two template instantiations.

Let's say you need a template with two template parameters.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class foo {};
```

and you want to emulate that using `namespace`s. For `M` number of types that could be used for `T1` and `N` number of types that could be used for `T2`, you will need `M x N` `namespace`s. You have increased your work load by an order of magnitude.

Next, let's say you need a template with tree template parameters.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> class bar {};
```

For `M` number of types that could be used for `T1`, `N` number of types that could be used for `T2`, and `P` number of types that could be used for `T3`, you will need `M x N x P` `namespace`s. You have increased your work load by another order of magnitude.

I hope you see the folly of rolling your own method of implementing class templates.

Comment: If in my situation, the template needs a single type. It does not increase my workload but I get rid of templates. templates make so many troubles. I intend to write the library and it is duty of user of this library to put it in the correct namespace or using it without namespace. is it logical to avoid using template and replace it with namespace is such a case?

Comment: What makes you think "templates make so many troubles."? All the compilers that I know of support templates very well.

Comment: lower speed (i have really experienced that) and also you cannot separate `.cpp` and `.hpp` anymore since the template does not have real code.

Comment: I assume you are talking about lower speed of compilation. With your method of `#include`ing `base.hpp` multiple time, I doubt you will save on that account. About the second point -- you'll have to provide the implementation in a `.hpp` file too. I am not sure what you mean by the statement "template does not have real code". How is the implementation of templates not real code. From my experience, template code is usually better code. It forces the programmer to think in terms of abstract types. It challenges them to come up with cleaner interfaces and implementations.

Comment: Yes I mean compilation time. with template it will be 10 sec without it is very fast. It is not scale of x2 much far that that. Linker has problem with codes which are declared as template but not implemented yet. It ignores them.